# Cant get to resources from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver

for some reason i cant get the string that are inside the strings.xml.
this is my code:

```
public class SDK_Referrer extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
String srt = context.getResources().getString(R.string.master);
```

its not recognising the "master" string.
when i check for what options i get in R.string...  i get things like R.string.copy, or R.string.cancel, or R.string.ok... and not the strings that i have in the xml file.
why is that?

Comment: Can you post your strings.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be `import`ing `android.R` instead the one from your own app;

Comment: ohh yeah!   the little things that can get you stuck!  thanks!